# How to show any non id column in google org chat

Tags: javascript

Hello I am new to Google org chart.

I am having 3 columns in my data table

```
[node, parent-node, tool-tip]
```

For some reasons values in my node column is repeating.

Therefore I want to have my "tool-tip" column to treated as "id" column and "node" column as view-able column.

Is is possible?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by myself..

[ { v : **tool-tip**, f : **node** }, **parent-node** ]